# some identical classes, act in each

Tags: jquery, class

I have a section where you see one or more messages that the user must agree, you should only leave one, if accepted and there are more shows the following
But I can not act on each of these classes separately

Then I have a container with several equal classes

html:

```
<div class="container">

    <p class="active"><span>1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sagittis justo sit amet odio posuere fringilla. Sed et nunc ligula. Cras faucibus porttitor ipsum.</span> <a title="Ver más mensajes" href="javascript:void(0)">Siguiente mensaje</a>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    </p>

    <p><span>1 Praesent sagittis justo sit amet odio posuere fringilla. Sed et nunc ligula. Cras faucibus porttitor ipsum, non accumsan sem varius mollis.</span><a title="Ver mensaje anterior" href="javascript:void(0)">Mensaje anterior</a>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    </p>

</div>

<div class="container">

    <p class="active"><span>1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sagittis justo sit amet odio posuere fringilla. Sed et nunc ligula. Cras faucibus porttitor ipsum.</span> <a title="Ver más mensajes" href="javascript:void(0)">Siguiente mensaje</a>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    </p>

    <p><span>1 Praesent sagittis justo sit amet odio posuere fringilla. Sed et nunc ligula. Cras faucibus porttitor ipsum, non accumsan sem varius mollis.</span><a title="Ver mensaje anterior" href="javascript:void(0)">Mensaje anterior</a>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    </p>

</div>
etc...
```

css:

```
.pieza .container p{display:none;overflow:hidden}
.pieza .container p.active{display:block}
```

and:

```
$(".container p.active").fadeIn("slow");
        $(".container p > a").live('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
           $('.container p').toggle('fast');

            $(this).parent().fadeOut('fast', function() { $(this).closest('.container p').remove(); });

        });
```

but it acts on all classes
how I can act alone in each zone?

thanks in advance

[example in action](http://jsfiddle.net/JcDzN/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe remove

```
$('.container p').toggle('fast');
```

or write

```
$('.container p', this).toggle('fast');
```

Comment: yes, that is. But i have 2 <p>, one display:none and the other with class="active" (display:block), and only can be one <p> visible. How to add "active" class to the <p> without class? http://jsfiddle.net/JcDzN/5/

Comment: How to add "active" class to the next <p> without class when i press the button? http://jsfiddle.net/JcDzN/5/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to assign a unique id tag to the classes.

Like so: `<div class="container" id="first">`

Then you can use `$('#first p')` instead of `$('.container p')`

Make sure that the id is unique across the whole of the page though, otherwise you will suffer from the same problem.